# Proving Properties of Markov Chain

Tags: probability, matrices

I want to prove that the queue length at a store is not a Markov Chain.

$Q_k$ is the queue length at time instant $k$, $V_k$ is the number of arrivals. At every time instant one customer is processed. Now if the queue length at $k= 2$ is $Q_2 = 3$. So at the next time instant the queue length would be $Q_3 = 2 + V_3$.
Although I know the answer that $Q_k$ is not a MC but I cant figure it out why. How can I mathematically see/derive this? Any hint is highly appreciated. Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

If you only consider the states $\{Q_k\}$ then with respect to those alone $Q_k$ is not a DPMC.  If it were, then we could determine the distribution of the next state $Q_k$ in terms of the current state $Q_{k-1}$.  The state $Q_k$ is determined by
$$Q_k = (Q_{k-1} - 1) + V_k$$
At step $k$ all gates have already been chosen and we need to choose the next states.  To know the probabilities of those outcomes we actually need to know $V_{k-1}$.  But we only have knowledge of $Q_{k-1}$.

We can make it DPMC by changing is as : $S_k = (Q_k, V_{k-1})$
Then given an $S_k$, we could calculate the joint density of the next state:
$$S_{k+1} = (Q_{k+1}, V_{k+1})$$